# GLib2+MSVC: Forking GLib2 to make "light" version of the library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cmake, glib

I'm using libGTS in a private project that is compiled using VC2008 express.

**short version**

libGTS depends on glib2, which (AFAIK) can't be compiled with VC2008. I'd like to pull relevant parts of glib2 into libGTS and make a fork. What's a good way to approach that problem?

**long version**

In order to use libGTS (originally uses autotools) I've already converted it to cmake build system.

Unfortunately, libGTS depends on glib2, which depends on libiconv, libintl, pcre, libFFI (in newer versions), pkg-config, where pkg-config depends on glib2. I.e. circular dependencies.

As far as I can tell, glib2 cannot be compiled using VC2008 express in any way, because it needs autotools, and converting Glib2 (and ALL the dependencies) to something like cmake would take too much time to my liking.

So far, I've managed build glib2 using mingw, and link mingw-built glib2 with msvc-built libGTS (glib2 has C interface, so it is possible), but this introduces problems in some cases, because glib2 and libGTS use different crt, and libGTS passes things like FILE* to glib2.

Fortunately, libGTS uses very small portion of glib2:

```
g_slist_remove_link
g_list_foreach
g_array_append_vals
g_array_new
g_array_free
g_strdup_vprintf
g_string_free
g_string_new
g_slist_foreach
g_string_insert_c
g_strdup_printf
g_strdup
g_strjoin
g_str_equal
g_str_hash
g_malloc0
g_ptr_array_set_size
g_list_reverse
g_list_length
g_ptr_array_free
g_mem_chunk_destroy
g_ptr_array_remove_index
g_mem_chunk_free
g_mem_chunk_alloc
g_ptr_array_add
g_ptr_array_new
g_mem_chunk_new
g_list_remove_link
g_list_free_1
g_hash_table_lookup
g_malloc
g_free
g_slist_length
g_hash_table_new
g_hash_table_foreach
g_hash_table_remove
g_hash_table_insert
g_hash_table_destroy
g_slist_find
g_slist_remove
g_slist_reverse
g_hash_table_size
g_hash_table_find
g_assertion_message
g_list_last
g_slist_append
g_list_free
g_list_prepend
g_list_append
g_assertion_message_expr
g_slist_free_1
g_node_destroy
g_node_depth
g_slist_concat
g_node_new
g_slist_prepend
g_slist_nth
g_node_prepend
g_slist_free
g_hash_table_foreach_remove
g_log
```

So I would like to pull relevant parts of glib into libGTS, get rid of all external dependencies (iconv/libintl - this subsystem doesn't need them) and make a "clean" fork (both libraries are LGPL, there are services github/bitbucket, so that's not a problem). "clean" fork means minimum amount of external dependencies.

I've tried pulling separate portions of glib2 (individual files) into cmake subdirectory in libgts (i.e. directory containing "glib2lite" library project), but this isn't really working out, because one file normally ends up pulling everything else. I've also managed to generate callgraph of libgts (to find actually used functions), but in the end it wasn't really helpful.

So what's a good way to approach this problem (making light version of big external dependency)? I'm sure somebody did something like that before.

Comment: How important is this? There are probably easier ways around this... have you considered cygwin?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: "How important is this?" Private project/research, writing for myself, I definitely don't need all the dependencies glib2 pulls with it. "have you considered cygwin" cygwin is a big NO. Code is meant to be portable and uses Qt. Making it depend on unix-like emulated system is a very bad idea. Also, cl.exe has better compiler performance on windows (according to my experience).

Comment: Oh, I agree. Just a matter of whether or not it's worth it for a private project :)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: "whether or not it's worth it" I'm unsure. It might or might not pay off, result is hard to predict. However, it should be easier to make "glib2 light" from glib than to write replacement functions myself from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the list of functions, don't pull anything out of glib2 - just reimplement it yourself (I've done that on a number of occasions for similar programs. One thing to note is that the string functions in MSVCRT and glib2 are almost identical, you can even get away with `#define` for those).

I'm looking at them more closely now, and it shouldn't take more than an hour or two to use STL and Win32 to replicate the functions. It'll take you much longer than that to understand and extract the glib2 functions.

Some pointers: slist is available in Win32, but the object is different. Same with STL. You'd probably be better off just using STL directly from the libGTS.

It's not as bad as I thought it was initially. You could probably pull the whole thing off in one night.

Comment: "and it shouldn't take more than an hour or two" Hmm... I'll think about it.

Answer (score 2):

GLib builds fine with MSVC and ships its Visual Studio project files in latest tarballs. See [the GTK+ MSVC wiki page](https://live.gnome.org/GTK+/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack) for more details.